# Replacing special characters in Java String

Tags: java, regex

I want to replace all special characters in the string shown below:

```
String a="Testâ€™â€µ"
```

I want to replace â€™ and â€µ with dashes (-). I have tried the following:

```
a=a.replaceAll("[â€™|â€µ]", "-");
```

This generates the following result:

> Test------

instead of

> Test--

How can I achieve the desired result?

Comment: Typo? Use  `(` `)` instead of `[` `]`. One represents groups, other represents *character class* which can match only *single* character from specified "range". Or don't even use `(..)`, just remove `[` `]`.

Comment: Before doing anything with regex, you have to solve first your encoding problem (utf-8 => Windows-1252 = correct utf-8 encoding).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use square brackets, as it represents a set of single characters to match (a [character class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/char_classes.html)).

```
a=a.replaceAll("â€™|â€µ", "-");
```

[Demo!](https://ideone.com/PwbdEy)